# Very new to python, looking for some clarification

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, statements

When I use this function:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sock,'html.parser')
for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    if string == "$":
        pass
    else:
        print string
```

It prints out the following values, skipping the $:

```
the
cat
has
nine
lives
```

Is this the best way to do this if I want to save this info into a database?

In the end what I want is a table that has |the|cat|has|nine|lives|

Comment: Have you tried `string.startswith`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index into strings as if they are arrays, so you could use string[0] == '$', or string.startswith(). e.g.

```
strings = ['$', 'the', '$big', 'cat']
for s in strings:
  if s[0] != '$':
    print(s)

for s in strings:
  if not s.startswith('$'):
    print(s)
```

You can also directly make a filtered list with list comprehensions like this:

```
nodollarstrings = [s for s in strings if not s.startswith('$')]
```

Comment: The code actually works how its supposed to, passing over if the string is $, however, your code actually doesn't work and only returns the first character in the string... Why is that? Also, I realized I put 'u $' in the OP, that was becuase I was using repr(string)

Comment: I was assuming "strings" is a list of strings. Is it just one string?

Comment: Running the code above prints:
"the"
"cat"
on my python.

Comment: Yeah, It seems that way. Can I use join to join all the single Strings into a list?

Comment: Join joins a list of strings into a single string. For example `"|".join([s for s in strings if not s.startswith('$')])` will give you `"the|cat"` from my code. You've edited you question to remove the starts with bit, so I'm not clear what you're actually asking anymore.

Comment: No big deal, you've already answered my question and more. Thank you!

Comment: Btw your .join doesn't work and returns: t|h|e next line: c|a|t

Comment: Running the first line from my answer, followed by the join in my comment returns `'the|cat'`, I've double checked on python 2 and 3 for good measure.